# Import site page getting error in SPD 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am trying to import site page form another machine to my share point designer i am getting this error.[image]

Using SPD I export the site page after that I try to import this page to another SPD solution that time I am getting this error.

Comment: is it in the same farm ?!!

Comment: No its not same farm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `import/export` site pages in SharePoint Designer is applied only across site collections on the same farm.

In your case,

- If you have one page, try to move the contents of this page manually, to your destination.
- If there are multiple pages, try to perform import and export to the library via PowerShell. for more details check [Export sites, lists, or document libraries in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428301.aspx)
- Develop your site page via visual studio so you can deploy it to another farm.
- Also, check this free tool [SharePoint Content Deployment Wizard](http://spdeploymentwizard.codeplex.com/) for moving the contents.

Comment: How can i move contents manually?

Comment: what're the contents of your page, are you have script editors! any other web part that can be exported

Comment: I modify the exiting site page. added 3 web parts also  change the layout of site page also. I want to this changes to prod server.

Comment: is it custom layouts ?

Comment: I change the layout means when you edit the page that time using Edit source  in this source I set the web parts in table format like tr td.

Comment: just move your changes to the destination this what I mean manually! please don't hesitate to tell me if you  need more clarification

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50431/discussion-between-admin-and-m-qassas).